# FontAwesome as a prop for an element

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Is there any way to pass FontAwesome as an element prop? I'm trying to do something like

```
<input
    placeholder={"&#xF002; Search " + searchFor}
/>
```

but that will display hex code as a string rather than decode to proper font value when it will be as

```
    placeholder="&#xF002; Search ..."
```

Any tips on that?

Comment: what is `searchFor`?

Comment: @larz A string passed to the search component like "Last Name" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to HTML-encode your UTF-8 symbol, which does not work because React is not HTML (although it looks a lot like it...)

So if you don't use the HTML-encoding but instead the JavaScript encoding "\uF002", your symbol should be displayed the way you want it.